# Viele und vielfache

Tags: difference

Meine Schülerin schrieb über Faust

> er war talentiert in vielfachen Bereichen.

Diese Formulierung finde ich falsch.

1. Er war in vielen Bereichen talentiert.
2. Er war in vielerlei Hinsicht talentiert.
3. Er war vielfach talentiert.
4. Er war in vielfacher Hinsicht talentiert.

stoßen mir dagegen nicht auf. Ich kann aber bisher nicht festnageln, warum Satz 4 besser ist als ihrer.

**Warum ist Satz 4 besser als der ursprüngliche - und stimmt das überhaupt?**

Comment: Wegen der Einzahl. *In vielfachen Hinsichten* klänge auch doof.

Comment: Ich finde die Formulierung kreativ und auf den Punkt gebracht. _Vielfach_ vereint die Attribute _Quantität_ und _Diversität_ in diesem Kontext. Du solltest zumindest keinen Punktabzug deswegen geben (ein Kommentar genügt).

Comment: @Ludi Ich würde an Deiner Statt wohl auch 4. bevorzugen, dennoch ist die Formulierung nicht notwendigerweise falsch, sondern _kreativ_ wie bereits gesagt.

Comment: @Ludi Du musst mich nicht Siezen, ich bin der Günther. Was die Frage betrifft ist dies wohl eher subjektiv, daher habe ich keine Antwort geschrieben.

Comment: Was genau ist die Frage? Ich lese hier nur lauter Aussagen. (*Meine Schülerin schrieb etwas; ich finde etwas falsch; etwas stößt mir nicht auf; ich kann etwas nicht festnageln*) - Keine einzige Frage. Daher: Keine Antwort.

Comment: @Hubert Du alter Pedant ;). Die Frage ist offensichtlich ob die Formulierung der Schülerin OK ist, oder ob eine der vorgeschlagenen Alternativen die bessere Whal wäre.

Comment: Die Formulierung der Schülerin ergibt im Gegensatz zu den Alternativen keinen rechten Sinn - die Bereiche, in denen sich das Talent äußert, sind ja gerade nicht 'vielfach'. Meine muttersprachliche Intuition ordnet die Vorschläge in absteigender Qualität als 2, 1, 3, 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Er war talentiert in vielfachen Bereichen.

bedeutet zwar, dass er in mehreren Bereichen (Pl.) talentiert war, aber die einzelnen Bereiche müssten vielfach sein, um eine derartige Aussage zu machen.

Sagen wir in Holz- und Metallverarbeitung, was ja von der Arbeit im Sägewerk bis zum Instrumentenbau (Holz) und vom Hufschmied bis zum Goldschmied reichen kann, 2 vielfache Bereiche.

Gemeint sind eher viele Bereiche.